# OpenCV Error while trying to save a Video

Tags: python, opencv, video, size

I'm trying to edit a Video and if use the "cv2.imshow" function i can see my edited frames,
but when i try to open the saved the Video i get a error "0xc10100be".
it seems like there is a problem with the saving of the edited frames and i think it has something to do with the size of the images. I tried changing the sizes, but to no avail.
Help would be appreciated, cheers.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
  
   

video = cv2.VideoCapture(".......mp4")
  
result = cv2.VideoWriter('filename.mp4', 
                         cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),
                         15.0, (960, 450))
    
while(True):
    ret, frame = video.read()
  
    if ret == True: 
        width, height = 450, 960
        pts1 = np.float32([[68, 755], [1908, 733], [63, 803], [1909, 787]])
        pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [width, 0], [0, height], [width, height]])
    


        matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
        Img = cv2.warpPerspective(frame, matrix, (width, height))
        imgOutput = cv2.rotate(Img, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

        imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(imgOutput, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        h_min = 19
        h_max = 60
        s_min = 73
        s_max = 237
        v_min = 20
        v_max = 188

        lower = np.array([h_min, s_min, v_min])
        upper = np.array([h_max, s_max, v_max])
        mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lower, upper)
        result.write(mask)

  
        
        cv2.imshow('Output', mask)
 
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
            break
  
    # Break the loop
    else:
        break

video.release()
result.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   
print("The video was successfully saved")
```

so what I'm doing here is taking a frame of my Video, cropping it, put an HSV filter on and get a Black & White mask so that only the relevant stuff is visible in white.
and i'm tring to safe those Black and white frames into a Video.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: there is no error in the code, the safed video file is only 1kb and when i try to open it, i get the "0xc10100be" Error code - hope that helps

Comment: Have you googled that error code? What did you find, and what did you try? Have you tried your code with different input files? Has your code ever worked before? If so, does it work again with the same input? `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')` doesn't do what you might think it does - where did this line come from? Did you write this code all by yourself, or did you copy it from someplace? Please [edit] your question and add as much information as possible - remember, we can't read your mind, and we aren't sitting at your computer.

Comment: you set `(960, 450)` in `VideoWriter` so you have to also resize frame to `(960, 450)` before writing. It NOT resize it automatically - it simply skips frame and you may get file only with headers which may have size `1kb`. Maybe first check `mask.shape` if you have correct size

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.